# Is there a way to handle a mouseover event on React-Vis Crosshair?

Tags: react-vis

I tried applying a handler to the object directly, without effect:

```
<Crosshair values{...} onMouseOver={() => {console.log("hello world")}} />
```

Is this perhaps harder than I expected...?

Comment: I know it's a little late but did you try to put your `onMouseOver` in your parent Plot/Chart component?